# Can I use switch-case inside if condition?

Tags: if-statement, switch-statement

I'm making a robot which can avoid an obstacle itself by moving randomly in another direction when it meets an obstacle. Can I use a `switch` case inside an `if` condition as a statement, like in the code below?

```
if(s1)
{
    switch(randNumber)
    {
        case 0:
            spincw();
            break;
        case 1:
            spinccw();
            break;
        case 2:
            up();
            break;
        case 3:
            right();
            break;
        case 4:
            back();
            break;
    }
}
```

I compiled this but it shows

```
error: a function-definition is not allowed here before '{' token
```

Comment: The error is telling you that you can't define a function inside another function, debug your code and see in which line you get the error.

Answer (score -1):

Yes you can call `switch` in `if`. you can not define a function inside another function. Can you please take a loot at function being defined correctly. Might be the problem is somewhere else. Can you please provide more detail.

Comment: No. I didn't define them in those statements. I define the functions including spince, spinccw, up, right, back outside void loop() function(I'm using arduino programming language).

Comment: I do not know about this language. But this example might be helpful. https://www.arduino.cc/en/Tutorial/SwitchCase2